# How can i turn off the bluetooh with ble manager?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using ble manager to turn the bluetooth on and off but when I move the switch it remains in the initial state and does not execute the if conditional.

```dart
body:Switch(value: state, 
      onChanged: (bool s)async{
          state=s;
          if(s==true){
              print("is true");
                         await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:3));
          initState();
            _bleManager.enableRadio();
          }else{
          print("is false");
          _bleManager.disableRadio();
          }
            }
      )
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the problem? Does the switch toggle? Is it only the bluetooth that doesn't toggle? Also, It would be better if you could share the widget tree that is including the `Switch`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code provided, you need to make some changes:

**1.** For changing the `state` variable, you need to call `setState`, so instead of `state=s`, use this:

```
setState(() {
  state = s;
  });
```

**2.** Don't call `initState()` inside the build function.

```
Switch(value: state,
          onChanged: (bool s)async{
            setState(() {
              state = s;
            });
            if (s == true) {
              print("is true");
              await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:3));
            _bleManager.enableRadio();
            } else{
              print("is false");
            _bleManager.disableRadio();
            }
          }
    ),
```

Comment: how can i execute a function when s == true?

Comment: The conditional is working fine. Just call the function: `if(s) function();`